# Quartz Scheduler running missing triggers even if misfire instruction is set

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I am having trouble with Quartz Scheduler. To be practical here you find my code of unit test:

```
Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
scheduler.getListenerManager().addSchedulerListener(schedulerTestListener); 

    Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
            .withIdentity(CoreTestConstants.TEST_TRIGGER, CoreTestConstants.TEST_TRIGGER_GROUP)
            .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                    .withMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires()
                    .withIntervalInMilliseconds(1000)
                    .repeatForever())
            .forJob(CoreTestConstants.TEST_JOB, CoreTestConstants.TEST_JOB_GROUP)
            .build(); 


scheduler.scheduleJob(getJobDetail(), trigger);

Thread.sleep(20000L);

scheduler.start();
```

---

The problem is, when the scheduler.scheduleJob(...) is executed I recognize that the task is not immediately started however when the scheduler.start() is executed I see that the 20 tasks is being executed immediately.

I mean, normally to my mind tasks should not be recorded or start until scheduler.start() is executed. But somehow the quartz system holds the state of tasks even before scheduler.start() is not executed, then when scheduler.start() call the missing task executions is triggered immediately.

Here the log:

```
09:32:45,005  INFO StdSchedulerFactory:1310 - Quartz scheduler version: 2.1.5
09:32:51,013  INFO SchedulerTest:47 - [test] Scheduler starting..
09:32:51,014  INFO QuartzScheduler:534 - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
*** [TIMER-TEST] 2012-10-10 09:32:51 / Test task is executed. Count: 1 / 1349850771037
*** [TIMER-TEST] 2012-10-10 09:32:51 / Test task is executed. Count: 2 / 1349850771040
*** [TIMER-TEST] 2012-10-10 09:32:51 / Test task is executed. Count: 3 / 1349850771040
*** [TIMER-TEST] 2012-10-10 09:32:51 / Test task is executed. Count: 4 / 1349850771041
*** [TIMER-TEST] 2012-10-10 09:32:51 / Test task is executed. Count: 5 / 1349850771042
*** [TIMER-TEST] 2012-10-10 09:32:51 / Test task is executed. Count: 6 / 1349850771043
*** [TIMER-TEST] 2012-10-10 09:32:51 / Test task is executed. Count: 7 / 1349850771044
```

As you can see even if I set the trigger to execute with interval in 1 seconds, it executed the missing tasks during thread sleep.

I tried to play around misfire instructions but it doesnt make a sense, it does not change the behaviour of the code in my case.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give the dependencies for quartz and spring?

Comment: quartz 2.1.5
spring 3.1.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK your problem is with `Thread.sleep(20000L);` while waiting actually the jobs are triggered and scheduled therefore when start is fired all scheduled jobs are starting, you can put Thread.sleep up to `Trigger trigger` so that it will begin triggering and scheduling after waiting. [Take a look for misfire policy](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/Trigger.html#MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_IGNORE_MISFIRE_POLICY)

Comment: The problem that I wanted to point out is the behaviour of quartz scheduling. Isn't it wierd to start the timer when the job is scheduled? Rather, the logical way to my mind is to both start scheduling and firing when scheduler.start() is called.

Comment: @Bariscan Yep you are right, I totally agree with you :) But it does not work like that... TriggerBuilder sets a trigger on the job and starts counting, when scheduleJob is executed quartz creates a schedule map according to the trigger (which has started already) and while waiting 20 seconds the trigger is still running and scheduling jobs, then when you fire start all scheduled jobs starts to run. you can look at an example from quartz http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-02